# Laptop battery full charged

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, power

I have a new battery pack for my acer aspire 4750 laptop, it hust a 2 weeks old, actually it is working pretty good.

I use batterycare to check charge level, so while i am charging and it reached 80% I remove the AC, then recharge it again at 40%.(the batterycare will show a pop-up if I reached 80% or 40% of the battery charged level)

But since yesterday i got these problem, the batterycare and the windows battery indicator notifying me that the battery is already full charged, but when I unplug the AC adapter, i can see the batterycare report and windows battery monitor that the charged level my battery is just 78%.

It doesn't even reached the battery care notification for 80% charged level.

Any idea about this?

I will appreciate for any help will come.

Thanks.

Comment: On my Lenovo I have observed that batteries are not charged continuously. If you specify charging to 80%, the battery will be charged to this level, then charging will be stopped until the charge level drops a bit (typically 5%) before charging is resumed, giving a saw-tooth charge pattern. If you remove the charger at any point you will be somewhere in the middle of the range and unlikely to be at the top of it. Domestic thermostats turn heating off and on in a similar manner.

Comment: If I am correct some Lenovo models has utility that you can limit the charging. but on my Acer laptop it doesnt have that feature, so I just relying on batterycare notification telling me that i already hit that level. but my problem now, is that it telling me that the battery is already full charges but actually its not.

Comment: I assume your BatteryCare feature is similar to my conservation mode, limiting the charge to less than 100% for a longer battery lifetime - in my case the charge level moves varies continuously around 55-60%. I have have a number of laptops with dead batteries: I have normally kept laptops on full charge at home, though this may not be the reason, but it seems worth using this feature, disabling it if I am going away, when I might need a full 100% charge (or rather 95-100%).

Comment: Actually it is not limiting the charge, rather it will just notify if the certain charge level reach. Keeping the battery always full is also not good, because of the higher voltage on every cell (source:[batteryuniversity.com](http://batteryuniversity.com/) i forgot the exact link). That is what i did on my previous battery and it just last for a year.

Comment: My Lenovo battery application has the ability to recalibrate the battery level indicator. It recommends doing this every few months and it would certainly be needed after a battery change. Have you done anything similar? (Thanks for the interesting link, by the way.)

Comment: I thought battery calibration should be done after 30 cycles.

Comment: The laptop when delivered will have a calibrated battery: a new battery with the old battery's calibration is bound to give misleading results.